# Javac simple package (JavaBib)

Tags: java, ant, build, package, javac

Dear Java Programmers,

JavaBib (http://code.google.com/p/javabib/) is a simple open source java package for which I would like to generate bytecode.

The source can also be obtained by version control via

```
svn checkout http://javabib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ javabib-read-only
```

Although it consists of only a few java files, I am not able to compile it using

```
javac *.java
```

I get

> cannot find symbol

error messages for nearly all of the files.

The source files of the dom package all reside in one folder. Therefore, I think it should not be a problem with the classpath. I have tried different values for it nonetheless.

There are additional source files in other directories. I tried copying them all in one directory and run javac in this directory, but javac was complaining about the same imports.

Unfortunately, I have hardly any experience with java and can't fix the problem myself.
Therefore, I would be grateful for hints towards additional diagnostics in order to pin down the problem.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 as operating system and haven't set any classpath or sourcepath variable. At least javac seems to find imports like "java.util.list".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What directory are the actual source files in, and what directory are you in when you're trying to compile them? Before ruling out classpath as a problem, what, actually, is your classpath? Have you set a source path?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, which are helpful to make my question more precise. I edited the question to reflect your comment."echo $classpath" returns an empty value, but imports like "java.util.list" seem to be found.

Comment: Post the full error messages you're seeing, i.e. what specific symbols are causing problems with the Java compiler. Also, are you sure that you [installed Java correctly?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html)

Comment: Since I installed it via the Debian package manager, the java installation should be reliable.